# SQLAlchemy boolean value is None

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I have this table in my Pyramid app

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    .....
    is_active = Column(Boolean, unique=False)
    def __init__(self, name, raw_password):
        is_active = True
```

When I did my test, it said `is_active` is None.

```
def test_register_user(self):
    user = User('user1', '1234')
    self.sess.add(user)
    self.sess.flush()

    #print user
    #self.assertTrue(user.is_active, True)
    user_db_record = self.sess.query(User).filter_by(name=user.name).first()
    self.assertEqual(user_db_record.is_active, True)
```

From my integration log I see when we are creating the row, `is_active` is set to None. Why?

Comment: If anybody has come here looking for an answer using SqlAlchemy and JetBrains' DataGrip, then do not use their visual editor to insert values into the table, it will ignore the `default` keyword and set the column's value to `<null>`. Instead use a raw SQL statement from the console, then the value will be set correctly.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have to set a default value otherwise None/NULL is used:

```
is_active = Column(Boolean, unique=False, default=True)
```

You wanted to do this in `__init__` but you used `is_active = True` (a local variable) instead of `self.is_active = True`.

Comment: Oh... `self.` was missing. Embarrassing. Thanks!

Comment: What should be the value of `server_default` for Boolean?

Comment: @Hussain [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-boolean.html) state a list of valid literals for True/False values and `'t'` / `'f'` are among them. I went with `server_default='t'` and it worked for me.

Comment: Seriously, with South/Django migration background, sometimes I think writing raw SQL migrations is a better approach compared to Alembic - at least it works in a predictable way...

Comment: @havelock one of the main selling points of SQLAlchemy ORM is to abstract the actual server/driver implementation (otherwise why bother doing anything beyond iterating over the `Selectable` and `type(NamedTuple)`?). So setting `default` in the column def and assigning the default value in `__init__`  will create both the default constraint on the server and assign it upfront during ORM object instantiation.

Answer (score 63):

If you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can use this command to create a server side default.

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import expression
active = db.Column(db.Boolean, server_default=expression.true(), nullable=False)
```

This will create a default value on the database so anyone can write to it and the DB will have the default value.

Comment: how is that Flask related? because this seems to be regular SQLAlchemy thing, I think you may have mixed up the `db.TYPE` stuff with `server_default` arg of SQLAlchemy `Column`?

Answer (score 29):

```
is_active = Column(Boolean, server_default='t', default=True)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: @ρss Alembic seems not to be generating SQL-level default value clauses in migration code from `default` alone, you have to supply `server_default` explicitly. As for the `'t'` value, please see [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12045698/sqlalchemy-boolean-value-is-none#comment69750602_12045897).

Comment: `server_default="true"` also works (note it is not the Python keyword `True` but a string `"true"`)

Comment: In my case alembic generate Column(Boolean, server_default=text("false")) and this was not working, I modified to Column(Boolean, server_default='f', default=False) as @far suggested and it worked properly.

Comment: One could use `expression.true()` rather than a literal `'t'` to assign `server_default` for portability.

Answer (score 1):

If someone is looking for a solution and using Flask this is how you'd do it.

It is very important to note that server default should be used inside the migrations file, not on the model itself.

once you generate migrations using a

```
flask db migrate
```

you should see new migration in the folder ( migrations/versions/XXXXXX.py )

```
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.add_column('users', sa.Column('confirmed', sa.Boolean(), nullable=True, server_default='f'))
    op.add_column('users', sa.Column('confirmed_on', sa.DateTime(), nullable=True))
    op.add_column('users', sa.Column('is_admin', sa.Boolean(), nullable=True, server_default='f'))
```

This is the place where you'd want to add server_default.

Answer (score 0):

Provided solutions here don't work for me (SQLAchemy 1.4.40)

```py
def test_entity():
    class Entity(Base):
        __tablename__ = "test_entities"
        id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
        is_active = Column(Boolean, nullable=False, default=True)

    entity = Entity()
    assert entity.is_active is True
```

```
Expected :True
Actual   :None
```

Comment: yeah..same issue.  Have you found a solution?